# before_validation on create not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In my model I have

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_validation :set_pending, on: :create
  validates :status, presence: true, inclusion: { in: %w(passed failed pending) }
  .
  .
  .
  private

  def set_pending
    status = 'pending'
  end
end
```

In my rails console I am trying to create a new Test

```
Test.create!(user_id: 9, runnable: true)
```

But I am getting error

`ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Status can't be blank`

What am I doing wrong? I am on ruby 2.1.8 and rails 4.0.13. Thanks

Comment: Btw, Test is a horrible choice for a classname. You will run into trouble.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My personal preference is to be very explicit when setting variables, and indeed you are missing a `self`

`def set_pending
    self.status = 'pending'
  end`